# Customizing the hamburger menu in Cordova Windows applications

Tags: cordova, taco

When I create a new application using the windows platform, I see the following menu:
[image]

How can I customize this menu, adding my own menus and perhaps removing the Share item?  Can I remove it entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple.  My minimum supported platform was set for Windows 8.1, so the menu that appears here is how Windows 10 renders the charms bar.  By adding

```
   <preference name="windows-target-version" value="10.0" />
```

into my `config.xml`, the hamburger menu disappears.